# Ionic build android on Linux

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, linux, ionic-framework

When I run `ionic build android`, I get this error:

```
shell.js: internal error
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/darko/Downloads/todo/false/shelljs_2da7bb00de48ebd25547'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1224:33)
    at execSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/shelljs/src/exec.js:56:6)
    at Object._exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/shelljs/src/exec.js:179:12)
    at Object.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/shelljs/src/common.js:168:23)
    at Object.getLinuxEnvironmentInfo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/info.js:187:24)
    at Object.getOsEnvironment (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/info.js:204:20)
    at Object.t (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/utils/stats.js:147:15)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/cli.js:135:16)
```

Please take note that path from the error:

```
 ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/darko/Downloads/todo/false/shelljs_2da7bb00de48ebd25547'
```

contains directory false, which I don't have..I think that should be `node_modules` instead of false.

Also, I had several problems before this error which I solved somehow, but I think I will get more errors as I go forward. Am I doing something fundamentaly wrong?

Comment: Have you tried removing platform and then adding it again ?

Comment: yes, no success